# pmdarima save auto.arima aic values

Tags: python, arima, pmdarima

Is there a way to save this AIC values?

I want to sort this values to see which model has lowest AIC in order to make cross validation to the ones with lower AIC's[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wr2hi.png)

Comment: Please prefer code as image : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw this issue in the GitHub page of [pmd arima](https://github.com/alkaline-ml/pmdarima/issues/64) (alkaline-ml/pmdarima).

The answer is from [Taylor G. Smith](https://github.com/tgsmith61591), who actively maintain pmdarima.

There is two ways.

**1)**

The first one is with the argument **return_valid_fits** set as True. See pmdarima 1.8.0 [documentation](https://alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/modules/generated/pmdarima.arima.auto_arima.html):

> **return_valid_fits** : bool, optional (default=False)
>
> If True, will return all valid ARIMA fits in a list. If False (by
> default), will only return the best fit.

**Example:**

```
import pmdarima as pm

sxmodel = pm.auto_arima(endog[:n_train],exog[:n_train], start_p=0, start_q=0, max_p=2, max_q=2,
                           start_P=0,start_Q=0, max_P=2,max_D=1,max_Q=2, m=7, seasonal=True,
                           d=0, trace=True, error_action='trace',suppress_warnings=True, stepwise=True)

sxmodel
```

In this first case the sxmodel will be a tuple with information about the fitted models

---

**2)**

The other one is using the **sys** module:

```
import sys
orig_stdout = sys.stdout
f = open('out.txt', 'w')
sys.stdout = f

# fit your model
model = pm.auto_arima(...)

sys.stdout = orig_stdout
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is as follows:

```
from pmdarima.arima import auto_arima
coeff = auto_arima(data, seasonal=False,m=0,error_action="ignore",information_criterion='aic', suppress_warnings=True, trace=True)
AIC_value=coeff.arima_res_.aic
```